# How to use pyspark's RDD in the correct way?

Tags: python, pyspark

I am new to Pyspark and RDD.
I tried to use RDD's to handle a 12 GB large CSV file. But at the end I cannot do anything with it. I tried to convert it to a SparkDataframe, I tried to make some actions like max,min,etc., I tried to save it as CSV file, but everything needs very long time? I think I didnt understand well what a RDD do and not do?

My Proceed:

First I loaded the csv in a pyspark Dataframe, cause i didnt found a good way to load it directly to RDD with a separator = "|". Then I convert it to rdd

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Practise').getOrCreate()
path1 = 'myFile.csv'
haystack = spark.read.options().csv(path1, sep = "|", header = True, encoding = "utf-8")
rdd1 = haystack.rdd
```

Number of partitions are 75.
Then I tried to use some Functions:

```
rdd2=rdd1.map(lambda x: 
             (x[0],x[1],myFuntion(x[2]),myFunction(x[3]),myFunction(x[4]),someFunc(x[2]),someFunc(x[3]),someFunc(x[4])))
```

And I think it worked, if I try to show it with ...

```
print(rdd2.take(20))
```

...I get values i expected.
It works in seconds. It seems too fast?

Then I try to get a Dataframe to make stuff like avg,min,max by each column

```
df2=rdd2.toDF(["id","title","myFuntion_1","myFuntion_2","myFunction_3","myFunction_4",..])
```

But than I wait for to long? I waited over 2hours and the terminal sayed still this loading-"thing":

```
[Stage 7:>                                                        (0 + 24) / 75]
```

Im confuesed why the maps and stuff are that super fast and know I'm stucked?

Comment: why not use a data frame?

Comment: Thought 12 GB CSV into a Dataframe and run multiple Functions on it would be to slow. But I didn't tryed it yet, maybe not. Never the less, would be great if could work at the end with rdd.

Comment: And I think the map function needs the rdd, is that right?

Comment: dataframes are faster and the new paradigm for a while.